# Printing selected data in a datastream?

Tags: python, string, printing, stream

I want to yield `'0.0'` from `stream2`, like it works for `stream1`. It doesn't work and it looks all fine to me.

`stream1` variable contains this:

```
{'stream': 'ABC', 'data': {'A': 'tra', 'B': 1605, 'C': 'GG', 'D': 25, 'E': '39.76', 'F': '0.02', 'G': 8271, 'H': 827, 'I': 16404, 'K': True, 'L': True}}
```

the line:

```
print(stream1['data']['F'])
```

gives

```
'0.02'
```

`stream2` variable contains this:

```
{'stream': 'ABC', 'data': {'C': 'GG', 'I': 164, 'E': '0.0',  'D': '1e-06'}}
```

but

```
print(stream2['data']['E'])
```

gives

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Essentially, I want to omit a stream where `E == 0.0` with

```
if stream['data']['E'] == '0.0'
    pass
else:
    cure_cancer()
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second print be `print(stream2['data']['E'])`?

Comment: Yes :D Was a mistake when posting this. Code is print(stream2['data']['E'])

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the error. When I changed `if stream['data']['E'] == '0.0'` to `if stream2['data']['E'] == '0.0':`, it worked like I would expect it (notice the change from stream to stream2 and the addition of the colon (:) at the end of the if statement).

Comment: If I set `stream2 = {'stream': 'ABC', 'data': {'C': 'GG', 'I': 164, 'E': '0.0',  'D': '1e-06'}}` then `print(stream2['data']['E'])` -> `0.0`— i.e. no `TypeError`.

Comment: Above code works fine for me. No errors seen.